# Get the number of days between two dates

Tags: sql, date, jupyter-lab, days

I'm working on JupyterLab(SQL) and I want to get the difference of days between two columns.

The values of the columns are in the format YYYYMMDD but they aren't integers

How can I transform the columns to dates and then get the differences of days.

Comment: can you share what you've tried till now, along with some examples to help us understand it better? some tips to help improve your question are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure about JupyterLab, but in SQL Server you can use DATEDIFF() to calculate this.  For example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS DateDiff;
```

See also:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Answer (score 0):

JupyterLab(SQL) supports SQLite, PostgreSQL, and MySQL databases:

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("20201005", "20201001");
```

**PostgreSQL:**

```
SELECT DATE_PART('day', AGE('20201005', '20201001'));
```

Comment: You don't have to format the column values. That is, you continue with `YYYYMMDD` format !

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the dbms so i am answering for oracle and postgres. You can use above answers but i like to convert them explicitly befor calculating difference.
so here is for
oracle -
`TO_DATE('20170103','YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('20200103','YYYYMMDD')` 
postgres
`EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_TIMESTAMP('20160101', 'YYYYMMDD')-TO_TIMESTAMP('20150301', 'YYYYMMDD')`